# Classifying the representations of $G=\langle(123), (456), (23)(56) \rangle \subset S_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

This is exercise 3 of chapter 2 of the book "Representations of finite and lie groups" By B. Thomas. My questions are in bold. I am essentially confused by two steps but I think I understand the entire question apart from that.

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of order $18$ in the symmetric group $S_6$ given by
> $$ G = \langle(123), (456), (23)(56)\rangle.$$
> Show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $9$ and four normal subgroups
> of order $3$. By considering quotients show that G has two representations of degree one and **four inequivalent irreducible representations** of degree $2$, none of which is injective/faithful.

---

My approach is as follows.

Observe  $|G|=18=2 \cdot 3^2$.  Denote $n_3$ for the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups. We see that by Sylow's theorem $n_3 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, so candidates are $n_3=1, 4, 7$  etc. However we also have that $n_3|2$, so $n_3=1.$  This means there is one sylow subgroup of order $9$, and another consequence of the Sylow theorems is that this group is then normal. We can construct such a group by considering the two generators of order $3$:
$$ H= \langle(123), (456) \rangle  \cong C_3 \times C_3.$$
Now this group has index $|G:H|= \frac{|G|}{|H|}=18/9=2$ and therefore it must indeed be normal in $G$. We can also use the generators (and one of its inverses) of order $3$ to construct $4$ cyclic subgroups of order $3$.
$$ N_1=\langle (1 2 3)\rangle=\{e, (123), (132)\} \cong C_3$$
$$ N_2=\langle (4 5 6)\rangle=\{e, (456), (465)\}  \cong C_3$$
$$ N_3=\langle (1 2 3)(4 5 6)\rangle=\{e, (1 2 3)(4 5 6), (1 3 2)(4 6 5)\} \cong C_3$$
$$ N_4=\langle (1 2 3)(4 6 5)\rangle=\{e, (1 2 3)(4 6 5), (1 3 2)(4 5 6 )\}  \cong C_3$$
We have thus found four subgroups of order $3$, but we still have to prove they are normal in $G$.

---

**(How do I know these exhaust all the subgroups of $G$ one can have of order $3$? I do not know how to formulate this/the exact reason). I also thought earlier I knew why these were normal, but I was mistaken.**

---

We can now use the fact that we may lift representations of quotients to the original group using the canonical quotient homomorphism.

$|G/H|=2$ and it is an abelian group (specifcally $C_2$) therefore by a corollary/consequence of Weddderburn's theorem we must have $2$ irreducible complex representations of $G/H$, which are both $1$ dimensional (I prefer to use Dummit and Foote corollary 11(1), page 861 for this). We lift these to $G$.

Now we can consider the quotients $$G/N_1, G/N_2, G/N_3, G/N_4 $$

---

**According to the hints and solutions section in the back, these each give a $2$-dimensionial representation, why?**

---

Once we accept this we can also lift these $4$ representations to $G$ to end up with $4$ (distinct/inequivalent) representations of $G$. The dimensions of the representations of $G$ we have so far are thus $1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2$. Then observe we must also have by theorem $10.(4)$ of page 861 of Dummit and Foote that:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^r n_i ^2 = |G|$$
However if we compare this to what we already have, we find:
$$ 2 \cdot 1^2 + 4 \cdot 2^2 =18 =|G|$$
So we indeed find that these are all representations by exhaustion. A lift of a quotient $G/N$ to $G$ always has $N$ contained in its kernel. We therefore know that lifted representations never have a trivial kernel and therefore they are not faithful (since they are not injective homomorphisms).

Comment: Your argument "these subgroups are cyclic, they are abelian, therefore normal" is not valid. Not every abelian subgroup is normal, as you can readily see by considering $\langle (12)\rangle$ in $S_3$.

Comment: Ah yes, only if the entire group is Abelian then every SUBGROUP is normal. that's right. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Try actually proving that the subgroups you have found are normal. Then think about what the sizes of the quotients are and what these quotients have to look like in order to have irred. 2-diml reps. A helpful way of thinking about $G$ is as follows: $H$ can be thought of as $(\mathbb{F}_3)^2$, a $2$-diml vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$, and the conjugation action of $C_2$ on $H$ is by an $\mathbb{F}_3$- linear automorphism. What is that automorphism? Once you can make sense of and answer this question, you will get normality of the four subgroups and the structure of the quotients for free.

Comment: It seems that the quotients are isomorphic to $S_3$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: And $S_3$ has three representations of dimensions $1,1,2$. The first being the trivial representation, the second the sign representation and the third one the one we are looking for (since $1^2 +1^2 + 2^2 = 6$). People seem to call this the standard representation of $S_n$, which is of dimension $n-1$, so in our case indeed $3-1=2$.

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer to your own question. It's a good way to let others look over your proof if you are not 100% confident that it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own questions in bold:

The list of elements in $N_1$, $N_2$, $N_3$ and $N_4$ exhaust all elements of order $4$ in $G$ and therefore these are the only four groups we can form of order $4$.

We can compute normality directly by looking what conjugation by the generators does to each of these subgroups. One can compute directly for $g\in \{(123),(456), (23)(56)\}$ that:
$$ g N_i g^{-1}\subseteq N_i$$
For instance:
$$(456)N_1(456)^{-1}= (456)\{e, (123), (132)\}(465) =$$ $$\{(456)(465),(456)(123)(465), (456)(132)(465)  \}= \{e, (123), (132)\}=N_1 $$

And then for a product of two  generators $a, b$ we have:
$$(ab)N_i (ab)^{-1}= a(bN_ib^{-1})a^{-1}\subseteq aN_i a^{-1} \subseteq N_i. $$
So if we know that the subgroups are left invariant under conjugation by the generators, the conjugation action of the entire group on the subgroups $N_i$ leaves these subgroups invariant, therefore they are normal subgroups by the subgroup test.

If we look at the quotients $G/N_i $ we notice they are of order $18/3=6$. There are two groups (up to isomorphism) of order $6$, that is $S_3$ (non-abelian) and $C_6$(abelian, cyclic). In $G$ we get that:
$$(23)(56) (456)= (23) (4 6).$$
But also:
$$(456) (23)(56)=(456)(56)(23)= (45)(23). $$
In the quotient $G/N_1$ these elements do not get mapped to $0$ or to the same elements. We therefore know that the quotient is not abelian. One can also do a similar check for the other quotients or investigate the order of the elements and realise that no element has order $6$. Upon inspection all the quotients have the structure of $S_3$, which has three irreps of dimension $1, 1, 2$ as was one of the examples in the lecture notes/textbook.